# Modificar el style del DatePicker en WPF

Tags: wpf, datepicker

En un proyecto de Silverlight modifiqué el diseño visual de todos los controles ayudándome con Blend, ComboBox, TextBox, DatePicker, DataGrid, etc. y lo guardé en un DiccionariodeRecursos.xaml y funciona muy bien para todo el proyecto.

Ahora estoy haciendo mi primer proyecto en WPF y pretendía utilizar el mismo diccionario de recursos, pero claro que varias cosas no funcionaron, por ejemplo la funcionalidad del DataGrid no es correcta, le digo que UserCanResizeColumns True y no lo permite, no se ven los ScrollBars y así...
El caso es que tuve que ir control por control para tratar de corregirlos.

Ahorita estoy con el DatePicker y de alguna manera modifiqué el Style del Calendar, pero no puedo asociarlo al DatePicker para que lo utilice, agrego imagen con un calendar (con style modificado) y un DatePicker (con el Calendar con style default) y agrego el código que tengo en mi diccionario de recursos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<!-- DatePicker -->
<Style BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="110" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="28" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkSeaGreen" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <!--<Setter Property="CalendarStyle" Value="{StaticResource DatePickerCalendarStyle}"/>-->
    <Setter Property="DatePicker.CalendarStyle" Value="{StaticResource DatePickerCalendarStyle}"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DatePickerCalendarStyle"
   TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}"
   BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Calendar}}" />

<!-- Calendar -->
<Style  BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}" >
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE4EAF0" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFECF0F4" Offset="0.16"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFCFCFD" Offset="0.16"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
```

.
.
.
Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Por favor [edit] tu pregunta agregando mas información: `funcionalidad del DataGrid no es correcta` ¿qué errores tiene?, en tu anterior proyecto ¿usaste alguna librería de terceros?

Comment: No, no utilice nada de terceros, solo el Blend para editar los style, el DataGrid ya lo modifiqué, y está funcionando bien.mi pregunta en este post, es cómo hago para ligar el Style que definí para un Calendar con el Calendar que usa el DataPicker, porque ahorita se pongo un Calendar (ver imagen) solo si presenta el Style que yo diseñé, pero si pongo un DataPicker cuando se abre su calendario NO abre el Calendar que yo personalizé, abre uno con Style default, espero haberme explicado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DatePicker tiene su Property específica para asignar un estilo al Calendario que contiene, solo declara el DatePicker así:

```
<DatePicker 
Style="{DynamicResource MyDatePickerStyle}" 
CalendarStyle="{DynamicResource MyCalendarStyle}" />
```

Un saludo!.

Comment: oh, gracias Leonardo, lo puse en mi diccionario de recursos, para que aplique así para todos los DatePicker que utilice en el proyecto: